# Programmatically administer Glassfish domain

Tags: java, glassfish, administration

I need to start, stop, set options on, etc. a glassfish domain in a programmatic way. The only resource I necessarily have available is `asadmin`. Hence I can

```
$ asadmin  list-domains
Foo running
domain1 not running
Command list-domains executed successfully.
```

However, I can't see any way to actually tell asadmin how to talk to a domain other than the default domain, `Foo` in this case. To do so I need to know the port of `Foo`'s administration server, and there doesn't seem to be any way to get that information. I could theoretically parse `Foo`'s `domain.xml`, but to do that I need to know where it is.

Ideally there'd be an `asadmin` option like `--domain Foo`, or at least a way to get `Foo`'s port or directory, but I can't seem to find anything along those lines.

Advice appreciated...

```
$ asadmin version
Version string could not be obtained from Server [localhost:4848] for some reason.
(Turn debugging on e.g. by setting AS_DEBUG=true in your environment, to see the details).
Using locally retrieved version string from version class.
Version = GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5)
Command version executed successfully.
```

**UPDATE:** For now I'm using the filthy hack of determining the location of domain.xml via `which asadmin` and chopping up the path. Then I parse the xml and extract the port. This is a terrible solution, so I'm leaving the question open to see if there's anything better.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the `asadmin` commands have the `target` option which is nearly the same as you want.

For example the command `list-javamail-resources` has the following syntax: `list-javamail-resources [--help] [target]`

with the following operands:

```
    target

    This operand specifies the target for which the JavaMail session 
    resources are to be listed. Valid values are:

    server
    Lists the resources for the default server instance. This is the default.

    domain
    Lists the resources for the domain.

    cluster_name
    Lists the resources for the specified cluster.

    instance_name
    Lists the resources for a particular server instance.
```

For a detailed overview of command operands and parameters see the [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2433/gentextid-110.html#scrolltoc).

Comment: Unfortunately in glassfish 3.1.2 the target option does not take domains as an argument for any of the commands I've checked ([example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24938/create-jvm-options.htm#create-jvm-options-1)). It appears it was deprecated in 3.1.1 and removed in 3.1.2, perhaps?